# Google Webfont shows up bolder and choppier in Safari than in Chrome, IE and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, safari

I seem to have a problem the other way round some people have here.

Here is the deal. http://www.mb-events.de/wordpress/ renders wonderfully on IE, Chrome and Firefox. However on Safari information like price and testimonials are displayed differently and I just can't find out why. The Google Webfont I use for that is 'Cabin'. I would post a side-by-side comparision, but can't due to being new.

I tried setting different fallback fonts and searched wether Safari does not like Google Webfonts in general.

My CSS is

```css
.entry, .entry p {
font: 300 15px/1.5em 'Cabin', arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try moving the stacking order of the web font your calling. I've always found that adding the svg type to the top of the stack always helps maintain the readability.

As an example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'encode_widelight';
    src: url('encode-sans/encodesanswide-300-light.eot');
    src: url('encode-sans/encodesanswide-300-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('encode-sans/encodesanswide-300-light.svg#encode_sans_widelight') format('svg'), /* Place your svg font here */
         url('encode-sans/encodesanswide-300-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('encode-sans/encodesanswide-300-light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

You could also try adding font smoothing to your css:

```
html {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron for helping!

I started with trying your second solution (didn't work) and am trying now the first one. :-)

Update: I found that the fonts are not loaded via @font-face, but via 'font'. I am using Wordpress and a customized WooThemes Canvas

Comment: Update: The solution was that I am daft - Safari on Windows isn't supported for years.